# Update default value

Tags: laravel, database-migration, updates, status

Good Morning Currently I am working on a job portal by the use of Laravel 8.

The idea: I want to show the applicants the status of each job (they applied on). so for example: Engineer (as position) when applicant applied in it. The application reach to admin can who can reject him or waiting listing listing him or accept him .

what I did : I created a new attribute in jobapplicaton table in (db) where all applied jobs_ids and user_id are linked and stored once they applied. this attribute is "status" and has a default value of "applied". The user can see first "applied" only. and admin have a chance to update "applied" to "reject" /waiting list or accept .

My code:Schema:

`Schema::create('job_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {`
`$table->id();`
`$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`
`$table->unsignedBigInteger('cv_id');`
`$table->unsignedBigInteger('job_id');`
`$table->string('status')->default('applied')->change();`
`$table->timestamps();`

controller: update methods:

```
public function update( Request $request, $id){ 
$job = job::with('applications.applicant')->find($id);
 $status->status = $request->input('status');
 $job->save();
 return view('overview.showcandi',compact( 'job'));

 }
```

admin view:(only the form)

`$job])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  {{ csrf_field() }}    {!! Form::select('status', array('1' => 'rejected', '0' => 'applied'), '0'); !!}`
`<input type="submit" value="submit" />`

Uservview:(showing zero value, but the default value is "applied" I dont know why ) that why i wrote like that

```
        <td>
                                @if ($job->status==0)
                                {{ __('applied')}}
                                @else
                                {{ __('$job->status')}}
                            @endif
                        </td>
```

the error: when the admin wants to change the status and click on submit the code gives me the following error

Creating default object from empty value I think the code is readin status as null although it is value in db is applied so how can I update the status now.

what I did : I created a new attribute in jobapplicaton table in (db) where all applied jobs_ids and user_id are linked and stored once they applied. this attribute is "status" and has a default value of "applied". The user can see first "applied" only. and admin have a chance to update "applied" to "reject" /waiting list or accept .

Answer (score 0):

@aly

you are trying to update object that are not exist ($status->status) may be your writing mistake please review them

```
public function update( Request $request, $id){ 
$job = job::with('applications.applicant')->find($id);
 $job ->status = $request->input('status');
 $job->save();
 return view('overview.showcandi',compact( 'job'));

 }
```

give a thumbs up if you got ur answer else you can leave a comment